# Create polygon grid that covers Earth

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

TL;DR:

Exact question would be how to generate semi-equal polygons of desired size e.g around 100x100m 1000x1000m, 5000x5000m grid that will cover Earth ?**

Background story:

I'm building a python based microservice that for given LAT,LON (WGS84) will return a json with some data, eg. matched country/city/or selected polygon grid.

Part with country/city/clutter works fine so far as I'm using shapefile and R-tree for quick check if Point is within area.

I'm struggling with the following case: imagine I have high numbers of GPS based samples with some data that I would like to e.g average over some geo-bins (grid).

I'm trying to divide Earth in semi-rectangular areas (for Merkator projection) that I could later on use with "contains" or "within" functions.

Currently it is done by SQL query and "GROUP BY" using SIN/COS and rounding

[Samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWjWP.png)

[into BINS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i2hR.png)

(LINKS TO PICTURES)

Since with shapefiles and upcoming data from the requests I'm working with WGS84 my idea was to jump into merkator (or webmerkator) generate geopandas Polygons and use to_crs function to jump back to WGS84.

```
world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]
world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
plotworld = world.plot( figsize=(20,10))    
plotworld.set_title("Merkator")
# Keep map proportionate
plotworld.axis('equal')

#Draw saple polygon rectangle (in merkator)
x_point_list = [0.5*1e7,0.75*1e7,0.75*1e7,0.5*1e7]
y_point_list = [-0*1e7,0*1e7,0.25*1e7,0.25*1e7]
polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(x_point_list, y_point_list))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}
polygon = gp.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom])       
polygon.plot(ax=plotworld,color='red')

#transform to WGS84
world = world.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
polygon = polygon.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
plotworld2= world.plot( figsize=(20,10))

polygon.plot(ax=plotworld2,color='red')
```

My question is: how to generate semi-equal polygons of desired size e.g around 100x100mx 1000x1000m, 5000x5000m grid that will cover Earth?

I've gone through a number of geopandas/shapely sites, that shows some tutorial about some shapes, bins however no One mention how to draw/generate bins with desired size.

I truly understand that dimension of the polygons will vary a bit, but it does not hurt me that much.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to do near the poles?

Comment: Hi @morf. Did you find a solution for this problem? I also want to divide the map of the world(land only) into rectangles and get there coordinates(middle of can be entire rectangle borders)

Comment: @chirgeo I've swithed to Uber H3 hexagons, there is a python library that works out of the box.

Comment: Thx! Really useful.